# Drawing popups in X11

Tags: user-interface, x11, xorg

I would like to draw a popup in X11.  Something like the slider that appears in KDE and GNOME when you press volume or brightness control buttons.  This is what it looks like in GNOME: [image: brightness slider in GNOME]

What library should I use to create such popups (unlike normal windows they should be without borders, etc. and possibly with some transparency)?  Would be nice if there were bindings for Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done in GTK+. The easiest thing may be to find the code that creates that and copy what it does (my system has a different volume notifier, I'm not easily finding the code for that one).

Roughly what you'd do is create a GtkWindow, set_decorated(FALSE), set_position(GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER), something along those lines.

I'm not sure of the best set_type_hint(). Maybe TYPE_HINT_NOTIFICATION or TYPE_HINT_SPLASHSCREEN. If you do set the type hint, it may not be necessary to set_decorated or set_position since the type hint may imply those with many window managers.

Comment: Thanks!  Setting type hint to TYPE_HINT_DOCK makes it look exactly as I want=)

Comment: DOCK is probably misleading; the window manager could legitimately do something that only makes sense for actual docks, such as keep maximized windows from overlapping it. NOTIFICATION and SPLASHSCREEN are already sort of pushing it.

Comment: There is no NOTIFICATION in pygtk and SPLASHSCREEN can be covered by other windows if set_keep_above is not set.  With set_keep_above SPLASHSCREEN indeed might be better.

Comment: you can also try NORMAL with set keep above, set decorated, etc.